# Scheduling is NP-Hard via vertex cover

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

Are there any existing proofs involving a reduction of the single machine scheduling problem (in any of its forms really) from vertex cover in order to prove its NP-hardness?

Particularly looking for a proof that does not involve linear programming (if it exists).